# Bash data filtering

Tags: bash, awk, filter, grep

I need some help with filtering data. How can I filter these to show me dates and prices but I only need data with unavailable set to false.

These are the data:

```
{"outbound":{"fares":[{"price":null,"soldOut":false,"unavailable":true,"day":"2016-12-01"},{"price":{"value":39.09,"valueMainUnit":"39","valueFractionalUnit":"09","currencyCode":"EUR","currencySymbol":"€"},"soldOut":false,"unavailable":false,"day":"2016-12-02"},{"price":null,"soldOut":false,"unavailable":true,"day":"2016-12-03"},{"price":{"value":21.24,"valueMainUnit":"21","valueFractionalUnit":"24","currencyCode":"EUR","currencySymbol":"€"},"soldOut":false,"unavailable":false,"day":"2016-12-04"},{"price":{"value":18.74,"valueMainUnit":"18","valueFractionalUnit":"74","currencyCode":"EUR","currencySymbol":"€"},"soldOut":false,"unavailable":false,"day":"2016-12-05"},{"price":null,"soldOut":false,"unavailable":true,"day":"2016-12-06"},{"price":{"value":23.24,"valueMainUnit":"23","valueFractionalUnit":"24","currencyCode":"EUR","currencySymbol":"€"},"soldOut":false,"unavailable":false,"day":"2016-12-07"},{"price":null,"soldOut":false,"unavailable":true,"day":"2016-12-08"},{"price":{"value":32.29,"valueMainUnit":"32","valueFractionalUnit":"29","currencyCode":"EUR","currencySymbol":"€"},"soldOut":false,"unavailable":false,"day":"2016-12-09"},{"price":null,"soldOut":false,"unavailable":true,"day":"2016-12-10"},{"price":{"value":16.99,"valueMainUnit":"16","valueFractionalUnit":"99","currencyCode":"EUR","currencySymbol":"€"},"soldOut":false,"unavailable":false,"day":"2016-12-11"},{"price":{"value":14.99,"valueMainUnit":"14","valueFractionalUnit":"99","currencyCode":"EUR","currencySymbol":"€"},"soldOut":false,"unavailable":false,"day":"2016-12-12"},{"price":null,"soldOut":false,"unavailable":true,"day":"2016-12-13"},{"price":{"value":9.99,"valueMainUnit":"9","valueFractionalUnit":"99","currencyCode":"EUR","currencySymbol":"€"},"soldOut":false,"unavailable":false,"day":"2016-12-14"},{"price":null,"soldOut":false,"unavailable":true,"day":"2016-12-15"},{"price":{"value":26.34,"valueMainUnit":"26","valueFractionalUnit":"34","currencyCode":"EUR","currencySymbol":"€"},"soldOut":false,"unavailable":false,"day":"2016-12-16"},{"price":null,"soldOut":false,"unavailable":true,"day":"2016-12-17"},{"price":{"value":16.99,"valueMainUnit":"16","valueFractionalUnit":"99","currencyCode":"EUR","currencySymbol":"€"},"soldOut":false,"unavailable":false,"day":"2016-12-18"},{"price":{"value":9.99,"valueMainUnit":"9","valueFractionalUnit":"99","currencyCode":"EUR","currencySymbol":"€"},"soldOut":false,"unavailable":false,"day":"2016-12-19"},{"price":null,"soldOut":false,"unavailable":true,"day":"2016-12-20"},{"price":{"value":16.99,"valueMainUnit":"16","valueFractionalUnit":"99","currencyCode":"EUR","currencySymbol":"€"},"soldOut":false,"unavailable":false,"day":"2016-12-21"},{"price":null,"soldOut":false,"unavailable":true,"day":"2016-12-22"},{"price":{"value":21.24,"valueMainUnit":"21","valueFractionalUnit":"24","currencyCode":"EUR","currencySymbol":"€"},"soldOut":false,"unavailable":false,"day":"2016-12-23"},{"price":null,"soldOut":false,"unavailable":true,"day":"2016-12-24"},{"price":null,"soldOut":false,"unavailable":true,"day":"2016-12-25"},{"price":{"value":21.24,"valueMainUnit":"21","valueFractionalUnit":"24","currencyCode":"EUR","currencySymbol":"€"},"soldOut":false,"unavailable":false,"day":"2016-12-26"},{"price":null,"soldOut":false,"unavailable":true,"day":"2016-12-27"},{"price":{"value":45.99,"valueMainUnit":"45","valueFractionalUnit":"99","currencyCode":"EUR","currencySymbol":"€"},"soldOut":false,"unavailable":false,"day":"2016-12-28"},{"price":null,"soldOut":false,"unavailable":true,"day":"2016-12-29"},{"price":{"value":55.99,"valueMainUnit":"55","valueFractionalUnit":"99","currencyCode":"EUR","currencySymbol":"€"},"soldOut":false,"unavailable":false,"day":"2016-12-30"},{"price":null,"soldOut":false,"unavailable":true,"day":"2016-12-31"}],"minFare":{"price":{"value":9.99,"valueMainUnit":"9","valueFractionalUnit":"99","currencyCode":"EUR","currencySymbol":"€"},"soldOut":false,"unavailable":false,"day":"2016-12-14"},"maxFare":{"price":{"value":55.99,"valueMainUnit":"55","valueFractionalUnit":"99","currencyCode":"EUR","currencySymbol":"€"},"soldOut":false,"unavailable":false,"day":"2016-12-30"}}}
```

Comment: Could you give an example of expected output?

Comment: This looks like a json file to me and I would advise using a language like python or perl to get what you want. You can call them directly from your command line if you know what you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a JSON parser like [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) to parse your JSON input & query whatever you want.

Assuming your json is located in `file.json`, the following will extract all entries from `fares` array that have `unavailable` to `false` and return only `day` & `price` :

```
jq -r ". | .outbound.fares[] | select(.unavailable == false) | { day: .day, price: .price }" file.json
```